# Windows RD Licensing: Double license from uppercase and lowercase user name

Tags: windows, licensing, remote-desktop-services

I was having problem with RDS license. So I checked my license usage, and found out that a user takes 2 license. 
The user DOMAIN\pajak below is using DOMAIN\PAJAK and DOMAIN\pajak. I can't revoke the license either from one of them.

[image: RDS Screenshot]

The license will expire on May, and I am short 2 licenses since there are 2 users having similar problem. When I right click on the name, I got a greyed "Revoke License" option. I am the administrator.

- How can this happened, and how to fix this? i.e, remove double licenses.
- Since it seems RDS CAL are case sensitive, how can I limit user to use only lowercase, and reject uppercase login from windows RDS?

**Note**: The user `Pajak`, means tax, is for government login, to check our finance. It is a requrement from our government to give a certain government liaison to audit our ledger in exchange for our special tax privileges. Thus, I can only limit our system not to allow him do something bad. But I can't trust them to put a notice on their system nor organization. I can warn the other user that I've stripped off, but not this user.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is old but the same issue occured with me on a windows 2019 rds farm.
This is what fixed my problem, from the Microsoft technet forums.
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/bb5d15b8-11f8-4ffc-99c8-afe491ce504a/2019-cal-user-license-duplicates-based-upon-case-sensitivity?forum=winserverTS

> This can be happen if the license attributes are not able to be
>   updated on the user account object due to lack of permission.  What I
>   would recommend is to first grant the necessary permissions in AD, and
>   then you can rebuild the database to clean things up.
>
> When things are working properly, if a user logs on you should see
>   their license issued as you do now in RD Licensing Manager, and you
>   should see the RD licensing attributes on their user account object. 
>   You may use AD Users & Computers -- View Advanced Features --
>   right-click on the user -- Attributes tab -- look for several msTS*
>   attributes such as msTSExpireDate, msTSManagingLS, etc.  If these are
>   blank and the user shows up in RD Licensing Manager it is likely the
>   permissions issue.
>
> You can grant the permissions using Active Directory Users and
>   Computers using below basic steps:
>
> On the OU that contains your users, right-click and choose Delegate
>   Control... , follow wizard On Users and Groups page, click Add and
>   then enter SELF On Tasks to Delegate page, select Create a custom task
>   to delegate On Active Directory Object Type page select Only the
>   following objects in the folder, then scroll down and select User
>   objects On Permissions page, select General, then scroll down and
>   select Read and write Terminal Server license server Once you have
>   updated the permissions, please log on with a user account that
>   doesn't have their licensing attributes populated and then check after
>   successfully logged on that the attributes now have values.
>
> Please reply back with your results.
>
> Thanks.
>
> -TP

Answer (score 0):

You can't revoke RDS **User** CALs.  You can remove/re-add the license pack or rebuild the database.
http://sigkillit.com/2017/08/31/remove-rds-cals-from-rds-server/