# Duplicate users in RDS licensing

Tags: remote-desktop-services, windows-server-2019

I'm about to purchase RDS CALs for a new RDS 2019 server currently in it's grace period. On checking the license console, we've got duplicate users in there. Is the username case-sensitive? Seems a bit unusual? I don't seem to be able to revoke licenses. Just concerned that we won't have enough licenses if we buy the exact number of licenses we actually have.

Or put it another way, why are there two entries for a single account when Active Directory usernames are case-insensitive. You can logon as TEST.USER or test.user - same account.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you help me with my software licensing issue?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue)

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/Licensing/servicecenter/Help/Contact.aspx

Comment: This isn't really a question about licensing or models but more of a question about whether RDS licensing is case-sensitive which doesn't seem right - AFAIK Windows Active Directory account names are case-insensitive. In fact that must be true because users are logging on with both quite successfully

Comment: it is a question about licensing, specifically Microsoft's kooky RDS per-user licensing which isn't even enforced. A license is a legal construct, and this license is only needed for any user account that has logged on in the previous 90 days, but people need to consult the vendor and get the information from them and not some rando web forum like this.

Comment: Your comment plus finding https://www.awingu.com/demystifying-rdp-understanding-microsofts-rds-vdi-licensing/ gives me the answers I need. Compliance is not enforced - you can over commit. So as long as we can show we have the number of licenses for the real number of users, then the duplication is not an issue and we are compliant

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is a known issue if the license-server does not have the proper permission to update the AD-Attributes

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/bb5d15b8-11f8-4ffc-99c8-afe491ce504a/2019-cal-user-license-duplicates-based-upon-case-sensitivity?forum=winserverTS

[Windows RD Licensing: Double license from uppercase and lowercase user name](https://serverfault.com/questions/958890/windows-rd-licensing-double-license-from-uppercase-and-lowercase-user-name)

> This can be happen if the license attributes are not able to be updated on the user >account object due to lack of permission.  What I would recommend is to first grant the >necessary permissions in AD, and then you can rebuild the database to clean things up.
>
> When things are working properly, if a user logs on you should see their license issued >as you do now in RD Licensing Manager, and you should see the RD licensing attributes on >their user account object.  You may use AD Users & Computers -- View Advanced Features ->- right-click on the user -- Attributes tab -- look for several msTS* attributes such as >msTSExpireDate, msTSManagingLS, etc.  If these are blank and the user shows up in RD >Licensing Manager it is likely the permissions issue.
>
> You can grant the permissions using Active Directory Users and Computers using below >basic steps:
>
> On the OU that contains your users, right-click and choose Delegate Control... , follow >wizard
> On Users and Groups page, click Add and then enter SELF
> On Tasks to Delegate page, select Create a custom task to delegate
> On Active Directory Object Type page select Only the following objects in the folder, >then scroll down and select User objects
> On Permissions page, select General, then scroll down and select Read and write Terminal >Server license server
> Once you have updated the permissions, please log on with a user account that doesn't >have their licensing attributes populated and then check after successfully logged on >that the attributes now have values.

Comment: Thanks I'll check this out